# Simple panorama with aframe

Tags: javascript

Simple panorama with aframe does not work.
I am an amateur in infiomatics. I copied the code in the htm file and also the js file in the directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>360° Image</title>
    <meta name="description" content="360&deg; Image - A-Frame">
    <script src="aframe-master.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>

    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately your question is really unclear, and I simply have no idea what you're asking. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular to get an idea of the sort of questions we need... then edit your question accordingly

Comment: im not sure if you really meant `infiomatics` and `aframes` and not `informatics/programming`  `iframe` or `a frame` can you edit your question and try to make it more clear what you need to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you want to execute the js code on the other file importing it on the html file.... check if your route is correct when you call the js file on the scr tag ... or if is neccesary to call a js cdn on your code 
https://code.jquery.com/